# 'BABEL_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs

when I run my react project with npm start command ,this error has been shown:

```
'BABEL_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I try `npm install -g babel-cli`, `npm install @babel/node` ,`npm install @babel/cli`
and `npm install @babel/core` but dose not work for me also i used another versions of node js but it still does not work!

How can I fix my error and run my project?!

***react version is  "^15.6.2",

"@babel/core": "^7.21.0",
"@babel/node": "^7.12.10",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6"
version of node js is 15.5.1
,***

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "npm install && npm run prod",
    "dev": "BABEL_ENV=development webpack --config webpack.dev.js",
    "development": "npm run dev",
    "prod": "BABEL_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.prod.js --color --optimize-minimize --optimize-max-chunks 15 --optimize-min-chunk-size 10000",
    "production": "npm run prod",
    "start": "npm run dev -- --watch",
    "lint": "eslint \"resources/**/*.js\"",
    "document": "esdoc"
  },
```

Comment: This issue is generally with windows. Are you using windows?

Comment: yes exactly...,